# LSTM without lookback for regression task

Tags: tensorflow, regression, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, forecasting

I'm working on an energy prediction problem for which I've trained an FFNN. The weather variables are known for predicting the energy. The model works, but I'd like to get more out of the data. So my idea was to use LSTM for better predictions. I know that LSTM works with the sliding window approach (3 dim data) where I can define a lookback period. So for the forecast I only need the past data, but I have the future weather data and I want the forecast to be based on that data and not only on the look back period.

```
x_train.shape = (16000, 8) (samples, features)  
y_train.shape = (16000,)  
x_test.shape = (4000, 8)  
y_test.shape = (4000,)
```

My FFNN looks like this:

```
model = Sequential([
    Input(shape=(x_train.shape[1],)),
    Dense(8, activation="relu"),
    Dense(8, activation="relu"),
    Dense(1, activation="linear")
])
```

My LSTM looks like this:

```
model = Sequential([
    Input(shape=(x_train.shape[1],)),
    Lambda(lambda x: tf.expand_dims(x, axis=-1), input_shape=[None]),
    LSTM(16, return_sequences=True, stateful=False),
    Dense(16, return_sequences=False, stateful=False),
    Dense(1, activation="linear")
])
```

I found out that with the Lambda Layer it is possible the train the LSTM without 3-dim input data.

I also want to make the LSTM layers stateful and set the shuffle parameter in the fit function to False.

Does this make sense? Is this approach possible for the LSTM? And can anybody help me to reshape the data for the stateful parameter. It only gives me the error:
`If a RNN is stateful, it needs to know its batch size ... Specify the batch size by passing a batch_input_shape argument to your first layer`.

I'm thankful for every hint!